# iPhone sending UTF-8 parameter in NSURL

Tags: iphone, utf-8, nsurl

i'm trying to search in google in a right to left language (hebrew arabic etc..) and i've tried this

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/search?q=امريكا"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

but no use at all it ignore the url and skip the method as if it's empty .. while if i put english characters it's work just fine .. is there another way for those utf-8 character ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat: I don't do iPhone programming, and don't know how the operations/methods that you're using are supposed to work.

However, it seems like the URL is not being escaped.

The [URL RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) is explicitly vague on character encoding within a URL ("This specification does not mandate any particular character encoding"). However, the URL is limited to ASCII letters, digits, and a small set of special characters. Everything else has to be encoded using [percent-encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1).

Although the URL syntax doesn't specify a character-set encoding, a well-behaved server should accept UTF-8 characters, *as long as they're percent-escaped*. So the Hebrew character Sheva, unicode 05B0, should be stored in a URL as `%D6%B0`.

To diagnose, you'll need to look at the actual bytes going over the wire. Not sure how easy this will be to do with the iPhone, but a logging proxy such as [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) may help (yes, I know, it's a Windows app, but I'm sure there's an equivalent for the Mac).